# How to communicate between C# and Wpf projects?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, interop

i'm working with 3 projects ,
one C# (let's called it A ) the  other two are Wpf projects(let's call them B,C).

The project B has a  main window which  contains a button ,when i press the button it shows  the project "A" main's window .(i've done that
by adding the right references and doing the code below in button click event handler :

```
            CsharpForm.Form1 d = new CsharpForm.Form1();
            d.ShowDialog();
```

, but The Problem i have now is how do to the opposite ??

i have a button in project "C"(wpf one ) and want it to open a window of project "a" (C# )

Do u  know any idea about this ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, A is WinForm and not C# as all the three use C#.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ElementHost](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2008/07/29/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms.aspx)

```
var wpfwindow = new WPFWindow.Window1();
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow);
wpfwindow.Show();
```

Comment: thankx it was helpful 
by the way i could manage this without the following line 
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow);

Comment: @Wazzz: If you don't want to handle keyboard inputs, then it's fine. You can get rid of that line.